# How to add file(READ ...) as a dependency to configure_file(...)?

Tags: cmake

I have something like the following snippet in a CMakeLists.txt:

```
file(READ api.yaml API_YAML)
configure_file(schemautil.h.in schemautil.h)
```

The variable `${API_YAML}` is used in `schemautil.h.in`

When I go to build, the configured file `schemautil.h` does not regenerate when I make changes to `api.yaml`.

How do I make updates to `api.yaml` trigger the `configure_file` line?

Also, if there is a better way to accomplish what I'm doing here -- i.e. stuffing `api.yaml` into source code at compile time, I'm interested.

Comment: In addition to the solution posted in the answer you could also move this code to a cmake script file and use `add_custom_command` to execute that script which allows you to specify dependencies and outputs. This would probably be better for a project that takes some time to (re)configure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dependency on that file to trigger a re-configure by adding

```
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS api.yaml)
```

See [CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.html) in the CMake documentation.